# The window of the AVD doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to test Android Studio and switch over if proves effective.

I start a test project with default parameter. I create a Nexus4 AVD and I run this project. The window of the AVD doesn't appear.

console log :

```
Waiting for device.
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus4 -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had just the same issue.

The solution is that you need to set the RAM for the emulator below 768M.

If the RAM is higher than 768M, the message at the bottom will be displayed.
[image: emulator]