# AVD (emulator) genymotion doesn't appear

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device, genymotion

I have a problem with avd and genymotion none of them are not start.

You can see when I start a emulator in avd the process of emulator start but there is not any window
[image]

And also when I click start button in genymotion a window will apear with caption of "starting virtual device" and after that a white window with caption of "genymotion for personal..." and after some second it will gone so I could not use neither of them.

I used the solution and it did not work
[The window of the AVD doesn't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881328/the-window-of-the-avd-doesnt-appear)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem of genymotion

It should run as administrator (and also I have to run virtualbox by myself)

But AVD steel has problem.(emulator.exe start but nothing shows)

**Finaly I found solution ,updating graphic card driver and skd solved the problem and now everything works fine**

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest reinstall it's latest version after uninstalling.